# When use listview inside gridview with tabbarview then screen not scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart

Screen Scrolling issue when i use listview inside gridview with tabbarview then screen not scrolling

please see my screen with tabview

[image]

Comment: Kindly provide code for this screen to check.

Comment: Please share the code for tab view content.  content inside tab view require to wrap with Flexible or Expanded

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. none will give you brand new code...so share the code what you have tried.

Comment: please give me proper code